# no-jk Equivalent in mod_proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, mod-jk, bitnami

I've always used Apache + Tomcat via mod_jk. To tell Apache not to forward /recources to Tomcat, you just put this in vhosts:

```
 SetEnvIf Request_URI "/resources/*" no-jk
```

How do you do the same thing with mod_proxy. If it matters, I'm using the bitnami tomcat stack and there is a tomcat.conf with:

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
```

Do I change that somehow?

Comment: Also note that there is a cleaner solution in mod_jk which is the directive JkUnMount. http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#<Location />
#  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
#</Location>

ProxyPass /resources !
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```